# Using url_for triggers AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'mapper'

Tags: python, pyramid

I am attempting to use url_for inside of a mako template with pyramid (using a book example):

```
${h.url_for(controller='formtest',action='submit')}
```

When I do, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'mapper'
```

I installed routes and put this in my helpers.py file:

```
import webhelpers.html.tags as tags
from routes import url_for
```

Googling the error, I read that url_for has been deprecated for Pylons. Is this true for Pyramid too? If so, what should I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're using Pyramid? ***Every*** thing that you have posted is about Pylons and not Pyramid. They are very different frameworks.

Assuming you are using Pylons, `url_for` was deprecated. You should instead be using the `url` global variable which is imported from `from pylons import url`.